# Where does iTerm store user preferences?

Tags: terminal, iterm

Where exactly is iTerm's user preferences file located? What I want is to sync this file over Github between several machines.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

Also note that you can set a custom location in iTerm Preferences under the General tab.

Comment: So this custom location is itself a preference, and therefore is stored in the preferences file that it refers to?   That wouldn't work, so it seems like this one preference has to be special somehow.  Stored in the usual place, and used for bootstrapping the rest?

Comment: @DonHatch Yes, that's basically what happens. On start, iTerm2 loads the default prefs, then syncs changes from the custom location. On quit, it writes changes in the default location's plist to the custom location. Most of that is done in https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/sources/iTermRemotePreferences.m